# Is there a way to hide Files from 'Files & Attachments' related list?

Tags: lightning, attachment, files

I think this is impossible but is there any way to hide Files in Notes & Attachments relatedlist of classic view? We moved only Admins to Lightning and wanted to roll out to other users slowly. Now after converting Attachments to Files, in classic view, we can see both Attachments and Files which gives duplicate viewing for users. Our Business team wants to hide Files without deleting them. Is there a way?

Comment: Can you just remove their access to the Files object?

Comment: ContentDocument object is not available to edit in Profiles section. I even removed access for 'Document' object, but it didnt help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest, instead of trying what you are saying, there are 3 related lists related to notes and attachments.

1. Notes
2. Files
3. Notes and attachments

Notes and attachments related list contains both files and attachment but files related list will only contain files, not the attachments.

So, remove the Notes and Attachments related list from your page layout and add a separate related list for  both i.e. Notes, files

Also, remember to enable files in your org by going to set up and search for general setting for the [image]file.

This way you will remove the duplicate problem. Also, it will ensure that you don't have to rework on converting attachments which users will create after the first conversion you have done.

Comment: this is the workaround am suggesting, but our business team wants to keep it the old way atleast for next few months. But this will be last option. thanks.!!

Comment: Unfortunately, if they want, you have to go for code.

Comment: As of now, I am going to mass delete all the Created files and will be converting from Attachments later. Thanks for reply.!!